# libgdx: sprite break like a glass

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a sprite which is ball. Let's say, it represents a glass ball.

I am rendering the graphics with `SpriteBatch`.

Is it possible in libgdx to have a breaking glass effect for the ball? Meaning, I want to split the sprite to different pieces with abnormal borders (not rectangular) and then draw them flying to different directions.

Comment: No, either do this via an animation or you have to replace the ball with several small sprites and let those move in different directions.

Comment: what about masking? Is it possible to apply say 10 different masks for each to have the different piece?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`PolygonSprite`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/PolygonSprite.html) to represent the non-rectangular chunks of your sprite.

To generate the chunks, I suggest picking a random spot near the center of your sprite, and then creating several triangles from that point to the corners and 2 or 3 points on each side of the square sprite.  You should be able to define a `PolygonRegion` for each shard, and use that to build `PolygonSprite` instances.

I haven't actually used the `PolygonRegion` API before (and it looks a bit obtuse), so you might want to check [the examples](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/PolygonRegionTest.java).